# read a file of records, extract fields into VLA’s, using insertion sort, search for user-specified target using binary search, print out result

Tags: c

I get the following errors:

```
search.c: In function ‘main’:
search.c:44: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fscanf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/include/stdio.h:447: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
search.c: In function ‘checkGrades’:
search.c:65: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
search.c:65: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
search.c:77: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void
```

Im basically a beginner in C so Im not quite sure how to correct these.
here is my entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TNARRAY_MAX  4096
#define LINE_MAX     200
#define FILENAME_MAX 4096
#define NAME_LEN     25
#define ID_LEN       6
#define SCORE_MAX    5

typedef struct
{
    char firstName[NAME_LEN + 1];
    char lastName[NAME_LEN + 1];
    char id[ID_LEN + 1];
    int score[SCORE_MAX];
    char grade;
} STUDENT;

int checkGrades(STUDENT grades[], int maxrecs, FILE* fp);


int main()
{
    char *file_name[30];
    FILE* fp;
    int rc;
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    STUDENT grades[TNARRAY_MAX];

    scanf("%s", file_name);
    fp = fopen("grades.csv", "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file for read.\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(fp, TNARRAY_MAX, grades);

    //count = checkGrades(grades, TNARRAY_MAX, fp);
    return 0;
}

int checkGrades(STUDENT grades[], int maxrecs, FILE* fp)
{
    char line[LINE_MAX];
    int rc;
    int count = 0;

    while(fgets(line,LINE_MAX, fp) != NULL)
    {
        rc = sscanf(line, 
                    "%25[^:]%*c%25[^:]%*c%6s%*c%3d%*c%3d%*c%3d%*c%3d%*c%3d%*c%2c",
                    grades[count].firstName, 
                    grades[count].lastName, 
                    grades[count].id,
                    &grades[count].score[0], 
                    &grades[count].score[1], 
                    &grades[count].score[2],
                    &grades[count].score[3], 
                    &grades[count].score[4], 
                    &grades[count].grade);

        if( (rc != 9) || 
            grades[count].id < 100000 || 
            grades[count].id > 999999 ||
            grades[count].grade < 0 || 
            grades[count].grade > 110 )
        {
            printf("Invalid Record: %s", line);
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            if(count == TNARRAY_MAX) break;
        }
        printf("NAME: ", grades->firstName);
    }

    return;
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: `int checkGrades(STUDENT grades[], int maxrecs, FILE* fp) { ...` ends with `return;`  (no value, no final `}`

Comment: Function `checkGrades` is of type `int` yet it ends with `return` so is not returning the `int` that was promised in the function prototype and definition.

Comment: 'fscanf(fp, TNARRAY_MAX, grades);' makes no sense.

Comment: `grades[count].id < 100000` is comparing a pointer with an integer (it is equivalent to `&grades[count].id[0] < 100000`).

Comment: `fscanf(fp, TNARRAY_MAX, grades);` is very wrong, but can you tell us what you are actually trying to do there? It looks like you meant to use the `fread` function.

Comment: i had more code there and deleted the rest but forgot to get rid of that line so it can be ignored (fscanf line)

Comment: @IanAbbott any suggestions on how to fix the pointer/integer error? Ive tried tweaking it a little but nothing i do seems to correct it

Comment: The `id` is a string, so you need to extract a number from it using a function such as `strtoul`.